# Why would $\mathbb P( S > x \lvert \mathcal{F}_{0})= \frac{X_{0}}{x}\land 1$ imply that $S$ is distributed under $\mathcal F_{0}$ as $X_{0}/U$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability, martingales, uniform-distribution

Let $X_{0}> 0$ a.s. and   $\mathbb P( S > x \lvert \mathcal{F}_{0})= \frac{X_{0}}{x}\land 1$. Why would this imply that $S$ is distributed under $\mathcal F_{0}$ as $\frac{X_{0}}{U}$ where $U$ is the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$,i.e.  $\;\mathcal{U}[0,1]$? ($U$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_{0}$ and $X_{0}$.)

My problem:

If $X_{0} < x \;,\; \; \text{then we have }\mathbb P( S > x \lvert \mathcal{F}_{0})= \frac{X_{0}}{x}$

If $X_{0} \geq x \;,\; \; \text{then we have }\mathbb P( S > x \lvert \mathcal{F}_{0})= 1$

I would have thought that $U$ would have to be $\mathcal{U}([X_{0},\infty))$, i.e. uniformly distributed on $[X_{0},\infty)$. Why is $[0,1]$ used?

Comment: Are $U$ and $X_0$ assumed to be independent?

Comment: @user4422 yes, it is stated that they are independent but I do not understand how we can choose $U$ in such a way

Comment: Write the problem as a transformation of the random vector $\left[X_0 \text{ } U\right]$ into the vector $\left[X_0/U \text{ } U\right]$, invert the transformation, compute the Jacobian, and then use the formula given in https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-probability/functions-of-random-vectors#hid4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mathbb P_0:=\mathbb P(\cdot\mid\mathcal F_0)$ be the probability under $\mathcal F_0$. The fact that $\mathbb P_0(S>x)=\frac{X_0}x\wedge1$ for all $x>0$ means that the random variable $S$ under $\mathbb P_0$ follows the [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution#Definitions) with scale parameter $X_0$ and shape parameter $\alpha:=1$. One way to sample the Pareto distribution is to take the inverse of a uniform variable, as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution#Random_sample_generation). More precisely, if $U$ is a uniformly distributed random variable on $(0,1)$, then the law of $X_0/U$ (treating $X_0$ as a “constant”, i.e., given $\mathcal F_0$) is Pareto with scale and shape parameters $X_0$ and $1$ respectively, so it has indeed the distribution of $S$ under $\mathbb P_0$.